# How can I improt a motion file (animation) and then connect a skeleton to a mesh with animation working?

Tags: modeling, animation, armature

I have been working with Daz Studio, Mixamo, and Blender trying to get proper animations working. If I try to import Mixamo animations to Daz it's broken, the main focus of this question is obviously Blender related. When I import the motion into Blender, it imports a fully rigged skeleton and the animations work properly, however the skeleton is separate from the mesh and is counted as a separate entity. how can I easily add the skeleton to the mesh and have the mesh function properly with the animation.

A major issue with this is the model (which comes from Daz studio originally) has many different vertex groups such as index finger Left, or right hip making parenting bones very difficult if not impossible (for me as an unskilled Blender user).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow the below steps:

- Select your armature (skeleton) and go to the armature panel and hit rest pose
- select your mesh and position it to be fitting on top of the armature
- while selecting the mesh hit <kbd>shift</kbd>+right click to select the armature as well
- hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> then choose automatic weighting

Now the mesh should be parented and weights assigned automatically with the armature bones.

Comment: thats actually what i needed thank you for that, now it just takes some minor fixing and should be useful, if only mixamo and daz help were as useful